# Yii2 query condition with exists

Tags: yii2, query-builder

I have a simple `Person` tree with `parent_id`.

I wont to build a (**Yii2**) query to find all *children* of a given `Person`, that are *parent* of someone else (a.k.a not leaves).

The output SQL should looks like this:

```
select * from person t 
where exists (select 1 from person p2 where t.id = p2.parent_id);
```

But cant find the right way to build this with the query builder, there is a method `->exists()`, but not much documentation/examples about it.

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if i understood correctly, but do you look something like this.

```
$subQuery = (new \yii\db\Query)
                ->select([new \yii\db\Expression('1')])
                ->from('person p2')
                ->where('t.id = p2.parent_id');
$query = (new \yii\db\Query())
                ->select('*')
                ->from('person t')
                ->where(['exists', $subQuery]);
$command = $query->createCommand();
print_r ($command->sql);
```

Generates sql like:

```
SELECT * FROM `person` `t` WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `person` `p2` WHERE t.id = p2.parent_id)
```

Answer (score 3):

You should try something like :

```
$tableName = Person::tableName();
$subQuery = (new Query())->select('*')->from($tableName . ' t2')->where('t1.id=t2.parent_id');
$persons = Person::find()->from($tableName . ' t1')->where(['exists', $subQuery])->all();
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html#where

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the right way with only queries, but if you use PHP also, then I think [this](http://blog.digibali.com/halaman/how-to-make-menu-tree-unlimited-category-subcategory-from-database-using-php-mysql) will help you.

And also try to search in Google with keywords: `hierarchical menu PHP`

Comment: thanks but, the question is specific for Yii2, and its query builder.
I will add a note to make it more clear.